# Image Sequence Texture

Tags: animation, shaders, image, shader-nodes

I was following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/ufvM2ixj2FI?t=1569) to create an animation. There was a step to create animation using **Image Sequence Texture** in shader editor. Even though author said that using keyframes on *offset* value will stop animation but it's not working. I've used 2.92 released version and the latest 2.93, however in both cases I have to change offset value on each frame so my sequence holds a particular frame while playing. Currently I'm using same approach for cycles and eevee but both are not working as in tutorial.

Is there any way to completely stop image sequence?

**upd-** [model link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/AZdF/urSCS1GzD)

[image: example]

[image: example 2]

Comment: “Cyclic” keeps the sequence going in loops. Would turning this off get what you need?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard unfortunately no, sequence did not stop

Comment: @vklidu oh, I see! Is there any way to convert it into matrix or an array? That would be handy

Comment: @vklidu it is said that keyframing offset on hold would do the job

Comment: @vklidu I've updated post with link to file

Comment: Answered ... and sorry - I checked tut closer and ... face sheet is not generated by node tree, it was just a guide (mockup) for animator to see what face relates to offset number.  I deleted all my comments that became useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep face during animation (before next keyframe) you have to change two things

- in **Texture node** change *Frame* value from 25 to 1, otherwise blender will play image sequence of all your 25 face frames

[image]

- in **Graph editor** you have to change interpolation type <kbd>T</kbd> to *Constant*, so the offset change happens in one frame

[image]

There is also one thing to keep in mind ... you are animating offset value, it means - offset set to zero is frame number one etc.

If you don't want to calculate and remember face -1 ... and would like to match offset number with first face you would have to use in face-sheet for the first face number zero, or rename file sequence - number two for a first image file (like *face_2.png*). Like that a first face on face-sheet will match offset number one.

[image]

Comment: oh my god, I really missed that step with setting frames from 25 to 1! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, you should be able to do it this way - produce an identical texture in the VSE but with the desired frame frozen and use that for your texture instead.

As far as I'm aware vers 2.8+ would still allow this.

Here is an original image sequence - 600 x 400.

[image]

...and after when paused midway through and re-rendered -  identical but with the freeze inserted.

[image]

.

Details for those who may not know how -

The original sequence can be laid into a VSE strip and 'Split' with SH-K at the frame after the one to be frozen.

Select the sequence at the right of the split section and drag it out of the way.

Go back to the remaining left hand strip and select it's handle at it's right hand end.

Pull that to the right as far as needed.  This will freeze that frame.
Play it to get the frozen interval right, and once ok -

Select the frames you moved earlier and drag them back to join up with the stretched right hand end of the left strip.

[image]

Set the render output to the same pixel dimensions as the original but to a DIFFERENT folder.
Render this to the same format and dimension as the original and use that for your texture.

HINT - the VSE has a habit of acting up when making changes to it's strips, so each time a change is made, save the Blend file as something different, (increment?) exit Blender, then reload to try it out.